# Calling a copy ctor and another ctor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a copy constructor defined in my code which is initializing data members of the object being created.
Now If I have to just change the value of the few variables, I am writing a new copy ctor.
So my question is, instead of again writing same code, can i just initialize particular different data members and for others, i can just call the defined one ctor in my ctor method.

example:
Already present

```
A::A(const A& cpy)
{ 
 a=cpy.a;
 b=cpy.b;
 c=cpy.c
}
```

Now I want to write my ctor as

```
A::A(const A& cpy, bool x)
{
   if( x)
      a=something;
   else
      a =cpy.a
   //call first ctor for other variables (b and c)
}
```

Thanks
Ruchi

Comment: Why don't you use an `init(a, b, c)` function?

Comment: This code is definitely not legal c++.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11 you may do something like this:

```
class A 
{
    public:

          A(const A& cpy) { a=cpy.a; b=cpy.b; c=cpy.c; }  
          A(const A& cpy, bool x): A(cpy) { a = something_else; }  
}
```

Comment: Was just looking for a useful link to make this answer. For instance: http://www.nullptr.me/2012/01/17/c11-delegating-constructors/#.UBJlv_ni58E Also, this is available is GCC 4.7 (search "delegating constructors") http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: Your first constructor looks like it's in desperate need of an initializer list :-)

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can call constructors in initializer lists:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a) {}
    Foo(int a, int b) : Foo(a) {}
};
```

However, there is a problem with your code, and that is that you try to create a copy constructor that takes an extra argument. It is then no longer a copy constructor, but a normal constructor that takes two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by having a default argument in your copy constructor like

```
A::A(const A& cpy, bool x = false)
{
   if( x)
      a=something;
   else
      a =cpy.a
   //call first ctor for other variables (b and c)
}
```

you can invoke it like

```
A objA;
 A b(objA, true);       // b gets a shallow copy of a
```

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor may have defaulted further arguments:

```
A::A(A const & rhs, bool x = false)
{
    a = x ? FOO : BAR;
}
```

Maybe that helps you write your code succinctly...